# Why does Joomla change the file permissions on installation of plugins?

Tags: file-upload, permissions, file-permissions

I have the following problem: I have a apache server running under the user `http:http`. Further the php scripts are evaluated through fastcgi and `php-fpm`. The php scripts are running under the user `foo:foo`. The files of joomla are owned by `foo:foo` and uploads are done via FTP.

When I modify the `index.php` of joomla to touch a temporary file it gets the correct rights (owned by `foo:foo` and file permissions `rw-r--r--`).

However when I install a plugin from within the backend, the files get the same owner (`foo:foo`) but another set of permission (`rw-------`). Folders get the correct `rwxr-xr-x`. (Remark: I installed the plugin directly from the web. So I did not upload the extracted files via FTP or similar. Instead joomla did extract the zip file.)

I understand that my configuration is ok in general but in case of an installation using joomla backend some bug seems to be triggered. What do you think? Is there any way of further debugging?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe check your PHP fpm configuration. This answer describes how umask is set https://stackoverflow.com/a/21319941/123594

Comment: In my case something like http://serverfault.com/a/764296/135637 but php-fpm instead of httpd was necessary. I will see if this will work out.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the file permissions on Joomla extracted files are 644 and the folder permissions are 755.

If you're seeing something different, then, as @jdog mentioned above, you will need check your `umask` settings (if you have a system administrator then I suggest you let him handle this). `umask` is used to remove deny default permissions (it is not used to add additional permissions). I would say you have your `umask` set to 077 for your Apache process.